Find the coordinates of the closest point on the surface of the ellipsoid to the line in space
I have an equation for an ellipsoid and a parametric equation for a line in space.
The equation for an ellipsoid is in the general form:
$$x^2/a_1^2 + y^2/a_2^2+z^2/a_3^2 = 1$$
The parametric equation for a line in space is also in the general form:
$$x=δ_1t+m1 $$
$$y=δ_2t+m2 $$
$$z=δ_3t+m3 $$
The line in space and the ellipsoid do not intersect, I now want to find the analytical formula for the coordinates of the closest point on the surface of the ellipsoid to the line in space. I saw in an article that a solution is to create a parallel line to the line in space, make the parallel line tangent to the ellipsoid, and then calculate the coordinates of the tangent point S.
I saw the analytical result given in this article:
$$S=\frac{a_1^2δ_1,a_2^2δ_2,a_3^2δ_3}{\sqrt{a_1^2δ_1^2+a_2^2δ_2^2+a_3^2δ_3^2}}$$
However, this article does not give specific proof steps. My mathematical ability is relatively poor. I can't solve the analytical formula for the coordinates of this point anyway, nor can I verify the correctness of the above formula. Can someone help me check and give the derivation steps? Thank you very much!

That "analytical result" cannot be true, as it doesn't depend on $m_k$.

If $P=(x,y,z)$ is the point of minimal distance on the ellipsoid, then the tangent plane at $P$ must be parallel to the line, i.e. the normal to the ellipsoid at $P$ must be perpendicular to the line:
$$
{\delta_1\over a_1^2}x+{\delta_2\over a_2^2}y+{\delta_3\over a_3^2}z=0.
$$
This is the equation of the plane contaning $P$, which lies then on an ellipse, intersection between plane and ellipsoid. But that plane also contains the point $Q$ of minimal distance on the line: a simple computation shows that $Q$ corresponds to
$$
t=-{\displaystyle{\delta_1m_1\over a_1^2}+{\delta_2m_2\over a_2^2}
+{\delta_3m_3\over a_3^2}\over
\displaystyle{\delta_1^2\over a_1^2}+{\delta_2^2\over a_2^2}
+{\delta_3^2\over a_3^2}}
$$
Once you know $Q$, the problem is reduced to that of finding the point on the ellipsoid (or on the ellipse in space) which is nearest to $Q$.

Your question has a flaw that if the line cross the ellipsoid, the point must on the face of the ellipsoid and satisfying ellipsoid face equation and line equation at same time. But I assume that you are not interested in this situation.Fine. First,
set $\vec P =(x_P,y_P,z_P)$ is the point you want,and the tangent plane is $$\vec N^T \vec X =1$$where $\vec N = (x_P/a_1^2,y_P/a_2^2,z_P/a_3^2)$ is the normal vector of the tangent plane. Of course, P on the ellipsoid face, so$$\vec N^T \vec P =1,(1)$$Besides,the line you give must parallel to the plane and yeild $$\vec N^T \vec \delta =0,(2)$$where $\vec \delta = (\delta _1,\delta _2,\delta _3)$ is the direction vector of the line. And the last condition is that the line directed by $\vec N$and cross the point P must intersect with the line you give. That means $$\exists  t_1,t_2,  makes:t_1\vec N + \vec P = \vec M + t_2\vec \delta$$where $\vec M$ is a point on the line like $(m_1,m_2,m_3)$.This means that these vectors are linearly correlated. So $$|\vec N ,\vec \delta, \vec M - \vec P|=0,(3)$$solve (1)(2)(3) and you can get the point P.
